# How to make a header ribbon responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eotamvwy/

HTML:

```
<div class="infobox-container">
    <div class="triangle-l"></div>
    <div class="triangle-r"></div>
    <div class="infobox">
        <h3><span>This is the Header</span></h3>
        <p>This is the content of the infobox.<p/>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify the CSS so that it is responsive?

I have a div which has the following style:

```
width: 98%
padding: 0 1% 0 1%
```

I want to insert the `infobox-container` inside and stretch it 100% and resize based on the above div.

Comment: Currently they have a fixed width. Why can't you change the widths to a percentage? What is holding you back?

Comment: I tried to set it to percentage but the right arrow is not aligning with percentage only works with fixed width

Comment: use percentages if you can't do that call a javascript function on window resize to resize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use percentage units for responsiveness and for triangles you don't need extra elements, you could use `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements on `.infobox h3`.

[image]

<kbd>**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eotamvwy/2/)**</kbd>

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.main-container {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
.infobox-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.infobox {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  background: #424242;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6a6b6b), to(#424242));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6a6a6a, #424242);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 90%;
}
.infobox h3 {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% + 22px);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  left: -15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  background: #3198dd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#33acfc), to(#3198dd));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #33acfc, #3198dd);
  font-size: 160%;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: #2187c8 0 -1px 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.infobox h3:before,
.infobox h3:after {
  content: '';
  border-color: transparent #2083c2 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 12px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  /* displayed under infobox */
}
.infobox h3:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2083c2;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
.infobox a {
  color: #35b0ff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
}
.infobox a:hover,
.infobox a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #35b0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="infobox-container">
    <div class="infobox">
      <h3><span>This is the Header</span></h3>
      <p>This is the content of the infobox.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just make a couple of small changes to make all the sizes responsive at least to the content:

The most important changes:

Use 'Calc' to set the width. Support is reasonable well (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)), but you could also solve this differently using negative margins (or probably other ways as well).

```
.infobox h3 {
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

The right arrow can simply be solved by setting `right` to `-12px`, just as the left one has `left: -12px`.

```
.infobox-container .triangle-r {
    right: -12px;
}
```

```css
.infobox-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.infobox {
    padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin:10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 90;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background: #424242;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6a6b6b), to(#424242));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#6a6a6a,#424242);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.infobox h3 {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    left: -15px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background: #3198dd;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#33acfc), to(#3198dd));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#33acfc,#3198dd);
    font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: #2187c8 0 -1px 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
.infobox-container .triangle-l {
    border-color: transparent #2083c2 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:13px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top: 54px;
    z-index: 2; /* displayed under infobox */
}
.infobox-container .triangle-r {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2083c2;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:13px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 54px;
    z-index: 2; /* displayed under infobox */
}
.infobox a {
    color: #35b0ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
}
.infobox a:hover, .infobox a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #35b0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="infobox-container">
    <div class="triangle-l"></div>
    <div class="triangle-r"></div>
    <div class="infobox">
        <h3><span>This is the Headewefewfewfewfewfewfewfr</span></h3>
        <p>This is the content of the infobox.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser? To me they are aligning just as they are in your fiddle, except that the right one is now always on the right.

Comment: Well, the arrow is on the right, like you asked (in comment). Vertically they are at the same position as in your fiddle, as specified by the `top` you have set. I don't know whether this is right or wrong, since you didn't specify any of this in your question nor in the comments.

Comment: My apology but as per my fiddle the arrow has to give it a 3D look.

Comment: Okay. I've updated my snippet and positioned the arrows accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this header ribbon to be responsive, you need to get away from using fixed-widths and instead combine `width:100%;` and `max-width: 270px;` (or whatever).

When you define the width attribute to be 270px, you are telling the browser you want this particular element to have both a minimum and maximum width of 270px.  If you are thinking responsively, what you actually want is for your element to expand as much as possible (`width:100%`), but to max-out at 270px (`max-width: 270px;`).

Thats the responsive bit.

What you are actually after is something closer to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/eotamvwy/3/

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.infobox-container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.infobox {
    padding: 3em 5px 5px;
    margin:10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 90;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background: #424242;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6a6b6b), to(#424242));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#6a6a6a,#424242);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.infobox-ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background: #3198dd;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#33acfc), to(#3198dd));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#33acfc,#3198dd);
    font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: #2187c8 0 -1px 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
 
.infobox-container .triangle-l {
    border-color: transparent #2083c2 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:13px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -12px;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 0; /* displayed under infobox */
}
.infobox-container .triangle-r {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #2083c2;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:13px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 0; /* displayed under infobox */
}
.infobox a {
    color: #35b0ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
}
.infobox a:hover, .infobox a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #35b0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="infobox-container">
    <div class="triangle-l"></div>
    <div class="triangle-r"></div>
    <h3 class="infobox-ribbon">This is the Header</h3>
    <div class="infobox">
        <p>This is the content of the infobox.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did a few things here:

1. I applied `* {box-sizing:border-box;}`, which does a nicer job at making elements "mold" to the widths that I tell them to (regardless of margins), [more details here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)
2. I took the h3 ribbon out of the infobox, and changed its position to absolute. My reasoning is that the h3-ribbon needs to conform to the info-box container's width, not the infobox itself. That way, regardless of the width, the ribbon will conform to its parent, and the infobox can occupy its 100% + margins (which should always be even on both sides.)

   3. And like I mentioned before, I changed the fixed-width of the infobox-container to `width:100%;max-width:500px;`. If you try resizing down, the ribbon stays in place.